# Time Complexity of Insertion and Selection sort When there are only two key values in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am reviewing Algorithm, 4th Editon  by sedgewick recently, and come across such a problem and cannot solve it.

The problem goes like this:

2.1.28 Equal keys. Formulate and validate hypotheses about the running time of insertion
sort and selection sort for arrays that contain just two key values, assuming that
the values are equally likely to occur.

Explanation: You have `n` elements, each can be `0` or `1` (without loss of generality), and for each element `x`: `P(x=0)=P(x=1)`.

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Fisrt at all you should have on mind what Time Complexity means.. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity, then know what each sort does to sort their elements.
After that you can think in border cases, like, 0 elements, 10000 elements (not really a border case), n elements, and 2 elements :)

Comment: @mayo That's not 2 elements. That's 2 keys, with `n` elements. I believe other downvoters didn't understand the question as well, since it's a nice one actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Selection sort:**

The time complexity is going to remain the same (as it is without the 2 keys assumption), it is independent on the *values* of the arrays, only the number of elements.

Time complexity for selection sort in this case is `O(n^2)`

**However**, this is true only for the original algorithm that scans the entire tail of the array for each outer loop iteration. if you optimize it to find the next "0", at iteration `i`, since you have already "cleared" the first `i-1` zeros, the i'th zero mean location is at index `2i`. This means each time, the inner loop will need to do `2i-(i-1)=i+1` iterations.

Suming it up will be:

```
1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2
```

Which is, unfortunately, still in `O(n^2)`.

Another optimization could be to "remmber" where you have last stopped. This will significantly improve complexity to `O(n)`, since you don't need to traverse the same element more than once - but that's going to be a different algorithm, not selection sort.

**Insertion Sort:**

Here, things are more complicated. Note that in the inner loop (taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm)), the number of operations depends on the values:

```
while j > 0 and A[j-1] > x
```

However, recall that in insertion sort, after the `i`th step, the first `i` elements are sorted. Since we are assuming `P(x=0)=P(x=1)`, an average of i/2 elements are 0's and i/2 are 1's.

This means, the time complexity on average, for the inner loop is `O(i/2)`.

Summing this up will get you:

```
1/2 + 2/2 + 3/2 + ... + n/2 = 1/2* (1+2+...+n) = 1/2*n(n+1)/2 = n(n+1)/4
```

The above is however, still in `O(n^2)`.

---

The above is not a formal proof, because it implicitly uses `E(f(E(x)) = E(f(x))`, which is not true, but it can give you guidelines how to formally build your proof.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really glad that there is some one who answer this question. I have read your solution and learned much from that.

Answer (score 0):

Well obviosuly you only need to search until you find the first 0, when searching for the next smmalest. For example, in the selection sort, you scan the array looking for the next smallest number to swap into the current position. Since there are only 0s and 1s you can stop the scan when encountering the first 0 (since it is the next smallest number), so there is no need to continue scanning the rest of the array in this cycle. If 0 is not found then the sorting is complete, since the "unsorted" portion is all 1s.

Insertion sort is basically the same. They are both O(N) in this case.

Comment: Just a clarification, that in each loop iteration of the selection sort, you continue the scan from where you previously stopped. So this is different than normal selection sort where you scan the same items multiple times, here you only scan the array once accumulatevly.

Comment: No. They are both in O(n^2). You ignore the fact that at the `i`th iteration, the probability to find the first 0 is biased, since you skipped elements that are not zeros. Obviously, you can tweak it (a lot) to make it `O(n)`, but that's not selection sort anymore.

Comment: The probability doesn't matter.  The algorithm is basically to scan the array once, and swap any 0s to the beginning.

Comment: That's not selection sort nor insertion sort. Nobody claims it cannot be done in `O(n)`, the question asks what will be the complexity of these two specific algorithms.

Comment: Well, if you use selection sort without any modification, that it's alway O(N^2) regardless of the input.  As for insertion sort, it's worst case is also O(N^2), and the best case is O(N) when the input is already sorted. So the unmodified algorithms would be O(N^2), but I think the question implies that we can modify the algorithms to optimize for the case of binary input. For example, when we look for the minimum value, we can stop when we find the first 0, rather than scan the rest of the array.

Comment: @gen-y-s Thank you all the same, for you have show me another quick way to solve the problem. :)